# Find first empty slot in an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

This is for a school project where we have to create an object, and then create an array of 20 objects. The object contains 1 string, and 4 doubles. I understand how to use a constructer to initialize the objects vairables. However, the part I am stumped on is how to determine the first empty space in the array. I'm assuming that each object in the array is *null* until it is assigned variables via the constructer. How would I go about finding the first empty spot in the array?

Forgive me if its a duplicate, but the ones I looked at either didn't have thorough questions or they were not what I think I'm looking for

I tried to do this:

```
int openArray;

for(int i = 0; i<markbook.length; i++) {
    if(markbook[i] = null)
    {
        openArray = 1;
    }
}
```

But it didn't seem to do anything, or work.

-Jordan

Comment: "I'm assuming that each object in the array is null until it is assigned variables via the constructer" ... correct. So, how do you think you'd find the first `null`?

Comment: add a `break` statement at the end of the `if`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are doing just fine. Your only fault is that you are using the assigne operator `=` (single equals) in your if-condition.

Where you should use the comperator: `==` (double equals)

```
int openArray = 0;

for(int i = 0; i<markbook.length; i++) {
    if(markbook[i] == null)
    {
        openArray = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

And you should save `i` instead of `1`. See my code example.